# What does it mean when standard deviation is higher than the variance?

Tags: standard-deviation, wiener-measure

I am currently studying Wiener's process from Hull, and it says that the path of the process is jagged because when $\Delta t$ is small, the standard deviation i.e. $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ is bigger than $\Delta t$ which is the variance. I am trying to understand what this signifies.

Comment: SD is the square root of variance, so when SD is larger than variance, it means that variance is less than one.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But what does that signify? For example, if I have a dataset where my standard deviation is higher than my variance, what insights can I draw from that information?

Comment: @NiRa The insight you can draw from that is that the standard deviation is less than one. Which can only mean something if there is another scale in the problem to compare it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The significance here is not that the standard deviation is greater than the variance. It is that the standard deviation goes to zero much slower than $\Delta t,$ (which happens to be the variance, but that fact is of little import, as far as I can tell).

This means that as you go down to small time scales, the absolute value of the derivative looks like $$ \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} \sim \frac{\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\Delta t} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Delta t}} \to \infty $$ so the derivative is very large and the path is very rough.

Comment: I now understand why the derivative does not exist for a Wiener process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the standard deviation doesn't have the same units as the variance, so a simple comparison of two particular values doesn't mean anything. You might have a formalism that allows you to claim that $0.5\thinspace\mathrm m>0.25\thinspace\mathrm m^2$, but you're not going to get much insight from that inequality. On the contrary, it should leave you feeling a bit dirty.

What's more meaningful is to say that as $\Delta t$ approaches $0$, the standard deviation approaches $0$ more slowly than the variance does. That might be what Hull means; you'd have to unpack the context.